# Construct JSONB from separate arrays of keys and values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, hstore

PostgreSQL has a very useful `hstore(text[], text[])` function which will "construct an hstore from separate key and value arrays". I am looking for a JSONB equivalent, but [there isn't one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that I can see. Maybe I will need to rewrite my statement instead, which I am looking into (but could use some help, as I can't think of a way to "merge" the two arrays)

```
SELECT HSTORE(ARRAY['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ROUND(n, 3)) FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1.001, 2.0045, 3]) n)::TEXT[]);
```

As you can see, the first parameter is "keys" and the second parameter is "values", but rounded down to three digits. Instead of an `HSTORE` object, I want `JSONB` in the end.

Please don't suggest casting from `HSTORE` to `JSONB`, I want to get rid of the `HSTORE` extension too ;) But yeah, that would work otherwise.

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.4.

**NOTE**: The function `jsonb_object(keys text[], values text[])` is awfully close to what I need, except values are restricted to `TEXT[]` and I need `NUMERIC[]`.

---

**ANSWER** (adapted from [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57150919/651980)'s answer)

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, val)
FROM (
  SELECT key, ROUND(val, 3) as val 
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], ARRAY[1.001, 2.0045, 3]) AS row(key, val)
) t;
```

Comment: You don't need to add the answer that solved your problem to the question. That's what accepting an answer is for.

Comment: Sure, but my answer is slightly different from yours (see the ROUND applied to the values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that both arrays always have the same number of elements, you can use something like this:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(k,v)
from (
  select unnest(ARRAY['value1', 'value2', 'value3']) as k, 
         unnest(ARRAY[1.001, 2.0045, 3]) as v
) t;
```

If you need that often, I would create a function for that:

```
create function jsonb_from_array(p_keys text[], p_values anyarray)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg(k,v)
  from (
    select unnest(p_keys) as k, 
           unnest(p_values) as v
  ) t;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that I will always have same-length arrays. Thanks for `jsonb_object_agg`, that's what I was missing.